# How to appendTo using JQuery if div is inside array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I've got a div inside a array that i want to appendTo, how can do that using JQuery?

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Compoenent } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import $ from "jquery";
const CircularJSON = require("circular-json");

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $(`<div className="bulkclass top" />`).appendTo(".innerDiv");
    alert(CircularJSON.stringify($(".outerDiv")));
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: [
        <div className="outerDiv">
          <div className="innerDiv" />
        </div>
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.content.map((item, index) => {
          return item;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Im using reactjs to run the application.

Here is a code pen:
[Pen For the source code](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-flower-fw5p4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you add differently the class name. You have to use an object as second parameter and use the key `class` for class names.

Another way is to use `.addClass(...)` method of an element.

Try this way:

```
$("<div/>", { "class": "bulkclass top" }).appendTo(".innerDiv");
```

**UPDATE:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import $ from "jquery";
const CircularJSON = require("circular-json");

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const divToAppend = $("<div/>", { class: "bulkclass" });
    divToAppend.html("WORKING PROOF");
    divToAppend.appendTo(".innerDiv");

    alert(CircularJSON.stringify($(".outerDiv")));
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      content: [
        <div className="outerDiv">
          <p>HELLO</p>
          <div className="innerDiv">TEST</div>
        </div>
      ]
    };

    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.content.map((item, index) => {
          return item;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the pen: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-hooks-td76u

Comment: Are you sure this work? Ive tried, but this seems to have no effect at all.

Comment: How to use addClass to append a div?

Comment: No, addClass is just for creating an element with a specific css class. Has nothing to do with append. I see your code pen, I will go to test, but I've noticed directly that you are not creating right the div the class is not correctly added that way in jQuery. Let me see the test

Comment: The problem is: i need this pattern of div creation. There is no way of appending a div that way?

Comment: Check out my code, I just updated the answer. You should see on the screen the text appended.